# Workaround for 403 error when using URLFETCH with Google Apps Script (external website)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, http-status-code-403, google-custom-search, urlfetch

I've used sof for many years (I almost always found all my answers!) but I'm quite stuck for the current project so this is the first time I post here. :)

I want to get the product price from [www.hermes.com](http://www.hermes.com) using either the URL or the product ref.
ex: https://www.hermes.com/fr/fr/product/portefeuille-dogon-duo-H050896CK5E/
ref = H050896CK5E
The URLs and Refs are stored in a Spreadsheet.
As I called UrlFetchApp.fetch function in my script, I got 403 error.
If my understanding is correct, that means the hermes.com server is blocking me out.

I also tried =IMPORTXML and it says that the spreadsheet cannot access the URL.

Here are the workaround I found: use Google Custom Search API to search the URL and iterate until the result URL matches the query.

[Current issues]

- If the object is out of stock or if the URL is not found, I am unable to get the price.
  ex:
  when I search https://www.hermes.com/it/it/product/cappello-alla-pescatora-eden-H221007NvA259/
  it returns me nothing.
  I know it can return
  https://www.hermes.com/it/it/product/cappello-alla-pescatora-eden-H221007Nv0156/
  but not the same colour (and sometimes the price does change between colours)

So my question was:
How would you do to bypass the 403 error ? (not bypass security of course but if you have any ideas how to retrieve the hermes.com prices, please let me know!)

I will paste the scripts below.
Thank you in advance.

→ What I used for hermes.com.
With the muteHttpExceptions = true, I get the captcha html

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.hermes.com/",
            {
              method: "get",
              contentType: "application/json",
              muteHttpExceptions: true,
            });
```

→ Result of above (a captcha html, I think hermes.com knows I'm a bot)

```
<html><head><title>hermes.com</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script>var dd={'cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMAs2XwactPh88AInQWTw==','hsh':'2211F522B61E269B869FA6EAFFB5E1','t':'fe','s':13461,'host':'geo.captcha-delivery.com'}</script><script src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js"></script></body></html>
```

→ What I'm using now (Google Custom Search)

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var start = (i * 10) + 1;
    var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + apiKey + "&cx=" + searchId + "&q=search " + query + "&start=" + start;
    var apiOptions = {
      method: 'get'
    };
    var responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions);
    var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
    var checkDomain = "";
    for (var v = 0; v < 10; v++) {
      if (responseJson["items"] != null && responseJson["items"][v] != null) {
        checkDomain = responseJson["items"][v]["link"];
        if (checkDomain != null && checkDomain == query) {
          productPrice = responseJson["items"][v]["pagemap"]["metatags"][0]["product:price:amount"];
          currency = responseJson["items"][v]["pagemap"]["metatags"][0]["product:price:currency"];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (productPrice > 0) { break; }
  }
```

Comment: About `So my question was: How would you do to bypass the 403 error ?`, the status code 403 means as follows. `The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) In this case, I think that the URL might not be able to be accessed from Google side. So, in this case, how about changing the language from Google Apps Script?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So do you mean like switching to other language like Java? Do you have any recommendation? I go ahead and check what are the best options too!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about your expected language, in your situation, it seems that the URL cannot be accessed from Google side. So how about testing it from except for Google and deciding the language?

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I checked online and if my understanding is correct, this means I get a server on my own (somewhere else than Google Cloud, GAS, etc) and have a program that accesses my Spreadsheet to get the hermès URL. I am going to try that and I will surely come back on SoF if there are any other issues I encounter. Thank you so much for pointing me the correct direction!